# Same password for apache and samba with ldap?

Tags: apache-2.2, samba, ldap

I am experimenting with LDAP. As I see it, apache uses the Unix password field to get the credentials and samba the field that is specific for samba.

I just use the LDAP server for a single server, LDAP runs in the same server. What I wanted is to use the same password for apache and samba (and mediawiki etc). Is it possible? If not, are there any alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apache can be setup to use an LDAP directory using mod_auth_ldap.  (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth_ldap.html).  Samba, I guess you figured out, can use an external LDAP source.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just make the passwords the same.  You can't have them all read from the same password attribute though, which seems to be what your thinking. They use different hashing algorithms to create their passwords.